# How to legally obstruct regular play in a football match

Tags: rules, football, officiating

In the last few minutes of the final of the Women's European Championship in 2022, the English team, who were leading 2-1, effectively obstructed regular play by retreating into a corner and making it impossible for German players to win the ball. When a German player managed to kick the ball over the line, the English players would take the throw-in and then immediately get back into the corner of the pitch. It was a somewhat unedifying spectacle, but perfectly within the rules of the game.

This made me wonder to what extreme you could take this kind of tactic. E.g. if the whole team gathered around the ball in a small circle, maybe even with their arms locked around each other, and maybe gave the ball a small kick every now and then to make sure that regular play was technically still going on, and they did so on their own half of the field to avoid being off-side, I can see no legal way for the other team to regain the ball. Would such an extreme and unsportsmanlike tactic be theoretically legal? Is there anything in the FIFA rules that the referee could use to stop this? Has any team ever tried something like this?

*(There was a time when, if players obstructed opponents from reaching the ball while not intending to play the ball themselves, the referee would call a foul for "obstruction". In recent years these rules seem to have been changed, and you now regularly see players aggressively shielding a ball that is rolling towards the edge of the field, in order to get or avoid a corner kick or throw-in. So I guess that "obsctruction" could not be used for the case I described.)*

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The answer to the linked question states that it's a foul, whereas this question asks how the English players were able to do it legally.

Comment: The linked answer makes it clear both why the **proposed** tactic is **not** legal, and why the **actual** tactic **is** legal, thereby resolving both components of the question here.